# Create automatically methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have this House class:

```
class House

  def self.building_steps
    [
      [Worker, :buy_material],
      [Worker, :blend_material],
      [Truck, :remove_ground],
      ......
      #more Tasks defined by [CLASS,METHOD]
    ]
  end

  def self.buy_material
    check_process(Worker, __method__)
  end

  def self.blend_material
     check_process(Worker, __method__)
  end

  def self.remove_ground
     check_process(Truck, __method__)
  end
  ............
  #More Methods that have same Method names like the building steps

end
```

As you can see in my code I have a lot of repetitions.

**My question** is how i can automatically define the class methods from the `building_steps` list.

So that I dont have to add the methods manually!

I search something like:

```
 House.building_steps.each do |step|
   define_house_method_with_name( step[1] ) 
     in this method do
       check_process(step[0], step[1])
     end
 end
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Hum good question.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`define_singleton_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method):

```
class Worker; end
class Truck; end

class House
  def self.building_steps
    [
      [Worker, :buy_material],
      [Worker, :blend_material],
      [Truck, :remove_ground]
    ]
  end

  def self.check_process(klass, method)
    "executing #{method}"
  end

 building_steps.each do |klass, method|
   define_singleton_method(method) do
      check_process(klass, method)
    end
  end
end

puts House.buy_material #=> executing buy_material
```

Comment: Good answer. You don't need the last two `self.`'s.